# insertAt in F# simpler and/or better

Tags: f#, performance, simplify

I would like to start some questions about simplifying different expressions in F#.

Anyone have ideas for better and/or simpler implementation of insertAt (parameters could be reordered, too). Lists or Sequences could be used.

Here is some start implementation:

```
let insertAt x xs n = Seq.concat [Seq.take n xs; seq [x]; Seq.skip n xs]
```

Comment: There are a number of good answers to this question already, but I wanted to caution that I think this function is probably rarely useful; most times you may use insertAt may be in an algorithm/implementation better served by mutables and System.Collections.Generic.List, or some key-value data structure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The implementation dannyasher posted is a non-[tail-recursive](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/F_Sharp_Programming/Recursion#Tail_Recursion) one. In order to make the function more efficient, we'll have to introduce an explicit accumulator parameter which makes the function tail-recursive and allows the compiler to optimize the recursion overhead away:

```
let insertAt =
    let rec insertAtRec acc n e list = 
        match n, list with
        | 0, _     -> (List.rev acc) @ [e] @ list
        | _, x::xs -> insertAtRec (x::acc) (n - 1) e xs
        | _        -> failwith "Index out of range"

    insertAtRec []
```

Comment: Pattern matching is making more complicated the code in this case. I search for shorter and simpler implementation.

Comment: You also asked for better solutions ... Yours is extremely simple.

Comment: @The_Ghost, actually, pattern matching simplifies understanding the recursion. Replace it with if-then statements and it becomes a mess.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an F# implementation of the Haskell list insertion:

```
let rec insertAt x ys n =
    match n, ys with 
    | 1, _      
    | _, []     -> x::ys
    | _, y::ys  -> y::insertAt x ys (n-1)

let a = [1 .. 5]
let b = insertAt 0 a 3
let c = insertAt 0 [] 3

> 
val a : int list = [1; 2; 3; 4; 5]
val b : int list = [1; 2; 0; 3; 4; 5]
val c : int list = [0]
```

My Haskell isn't good enough to know whether the case of passing an empty list is correctly taken care of in the Haskell function. In F# we explicitly take care of the empty list in the second match case.

Danny

Answer (score 2):

Tail-recursive using Seqs:

```
let rec insertAt = function
    | 0, x, xs -> seq { yield x; yield! xs }
    | n, x, xs -> seq { yield Seq.hd xs; yield! insertAt (n-1, x, Seq.skip 1 xs) }
```

Comment: I like this solution! But I don't like that are used tuples instead of separate arguments. With tuples it's harder to use partial parameter application.

Comment: @The_Ghost, just use `let rec insertAt n x xs = match n, x, xs | 0, x, xs -> ...` etc, which will get rid of the tupled args.

Answer (score 1):

For case you really want to work with sequence:

```
let insertAt x ys n =
  let i = ref n
  seq {
    for y in ys do
    decr i
    if !i = 0 then yield x
    yield y
  }
```

For all other cases dannyasher's answer is definitly nicer and faster.

Answer (score 0):

From the Haskell Wiki - http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/99_questions/21_to_28

```
insertAt :: a -> [a] -> Int -> [a]
insertAt x ys     1 = x:ys
insertAt x (y:ys) n = y:insertAt x ys (n-1)
```

I'm not an F# programmer so I don't know the equivalent syntax for F# but this is a nice recursive definition for insertAt

Comment: Yes, I got the quiz from there. But I'm trying to implement it in F# to practice. So I would like to find simpler implementation than mine exactly in F#. The simplest I got to in Haskell was: 

insertAt x xs n = take n xs ++ [x] ++ drop n xs

But this is not so optimal. May be some simple and optimal Haskell answer will be:

insertAt x xs n = let (before,after) = splitAt n xs in before ++ [x] ++ after